# ssh user@IP sh <command> missed environment variables

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, profile

I use an approach

> ssh user@IP sh [runme.sh]

to execute script remotely, this works fine. But I got one problem, that is in runme.sh, I can't get any envirnoment variables which are defined in ~/.bashrc. If I launch the script locally, everything goes fine, but how can I get those environment configurations with ssh command?

One workable approach is to add one line

> . ~/.bashrc

in every runme.sh in the very beginning, but in this way, I need to modify a lot of "runme.sh" files on clients. Is there a better idea ?

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't have environment variable definitions in `~/.bashrc`, that file is for configurations for bash when running interactively (aliases, prompts, that kind of stuff). The place for environment variables is `~/.profile`; it's read when you start an interactive session in text mode, and on many systems also in graphics mode. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980) for more details.

To run a bash shell that sets your environment variables as usual for the remote machine, you can do

```
ssh user@IP bash --login runme.sh
```

For other shells, make them read your `.profile` (and perhaps `/etc/profile` as well):

```
ssh user@IP '. /etc/profile; . ~/.profile; exec runme.sh'
```

If you want to copy environment variables from your local session over ssh, that's possible but usually disabled on the server side. Read [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process/207262#207262) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
ssh user@IP -- '. ~/.bashrc; sh runme.sh'
```

You should probably be a bit careful about the distinction between `sh` and `bash`.  If you have fancy customizations in `.bashrc`, and `sh` is something like dash, then this might fail.

Comment: `ssh user@IP . ~/.bashrc; sh runme.sh` this could work, but `ssh user@IP '. ~/.bashrc; sh runme.sh'` still can not get env vars, I'm confused. What's wrong with a signle quote? Nor double quotes could work... I'm on ubuntu box.

Comment: @Yang: When you run that first command, `runme.sh` is executed on the local machine. Your problem may be that [`.bashrc` is exiting early](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12164/12169#12169), in which case the fix is to [not define environment variables there but in `.profile`](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980).

Answer (score 0):

How about sourcing the `/etc/profile` on `ssh` command?

```
ssh user@host "source /etc/profile; sh runme.sh"
```

Adopted from an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-manu)

Comment: There're mutiple palces we can set environment variables, if you set it in /etc/profile, I'm sure it works. Thank you Andy.

Answer (score 0):

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Typically `~/.bashrc` will start with some form of the previous code. When you execute a command directly with ssh, bash will not be running interactively so you need to make sure that the environment variables you want to set are before any such line.

Answer (score 0):

On the target system, is `sh` actually `bash`?  It very well may not be, which is one potential reason for your `.bashrc` not being read automatically.

Does running `bash runme.sh` work?  If so, that's your problem.

Also as someone pointed out already, if you have anything that detects whether your shell is running interactively in your `.bashrc`, your variables must be set above this code.